# how to create user without alter table permission

Tags: oracle19c

I would like to create a user that does not have permission to modify existing tables.
No matter what I try. Always the user can change existing tables even if he has only create session permission.  (Oracle 19.14 Database)

```
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0

SQL> CREATE USER kirk IDENTIFIED BY hallo;

User created.

SQL>  grant create session to kirk;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn kirk/hallo
Connected.
SQL>  create table test (id int);
 create table test (id int)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

This is what I expected. The user does not have permission to create table.
So we log in as sys and create the table:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> create table kirk.test (id int);

Table created.
```

now we log in as kirk again and try to modify the table:

```
SQL> conn kirk/hallo
Connected.
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(38)

SQL> alter table test add name char(50);

Table altered.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(38)
 NAME                                               CHAR(50)

SQL>
```

Why can krik change this table?
(kirk has only create session privileges)

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You can't; the prerequisites for [alter table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html) are "The table must be in your own schema, or ...." some other things that aren't relevant. I guess you could use a DDL trigger. But why are you trying this - why not just create a different user with DML privs on on `kirk`, and never let anyone log in as that user?

Comment: Theoretically you can prevent accidental table drop by ddl triggers. But generally owner(kirk) is the master of the table. He owns it and he can what ever he wants. General solution is create another user who has only DML rights to table.